# Correctly displaying list items in a combobox and reacting to an item selection

Tags: c#, winforms, list, data-binding, combobox

I have created a a list "employeeList" of  my custom class objects.
The class is called "Employee":

```
public class Employee
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public string region;
    public Position position;
    public List<double> goals;
    public List<double> tests;
    public double correlation;
    public Employee supervisor;
    ....
}
```

Here I pass the List to the Form.cs and bind my list to the combobox

```
var employeeList = correlation.ComputeCorrelation();
var bSource = new BindingSource();
bSource.DataSource = employeeList;
comboBox1.DataSource = bSource.DataSource;
Employee f = (Employee)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Honestly, I haven't completely figured out how that whole binding thing works but it's not an issue.The thing is, once the binding is done, all the items appear in the combobox with their default names like Correlation_new.Employee. What I want to do is display the item by a field "name" from the Employee class. How do I do that?

Also, I just can't figure out how to handle an event of selecting an item in a combobox. I need to get the contents of that item.

Comment: You really need to read a tutorial.  You are asking chapter one questions here.  Your Employee class is using fields, you probably want those to be properties.  And yes, you can use the SelectedIndexChanged event or something similar for when the ComboBox's selected item changes.  You can also override the ToString function of the Employee class to fix the displayed content in the ComboBox.

Comment: @LarsTech
well, SelectedIndexChanged just doesn't work.
    private void combobox1__TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't really describe the problem. What you wrote looks like the TextChanged event.  You have to wire the correct event, too, either manually or through the designer.

Comment: I used that code too. The event doesn't happen and I don't know why. Everything is written correctly

 private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Employee f = (Employee)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
            listBox1.Text = f.firstName;

        }

Comment: Did you wire up the event?  From the designer properties window, select the lightning bolt, double-click on an event, etc.

Comment: I didn't find the lightning bolt but I wired it up manually. Thank you, that completely solves my second question

Comment: You also answered the first one so yeah. You're awesome

Answer (score 0):

***Your Employee.cs class should be written as below:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace YourProjectName
{
public class Employee
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public string region;
    public Position position;
    public List<double> goals;
    public List<double> tests;
    public double correlation;
    public Employee supervisor;
    public String GetFirstName() { return firstName; }
    public String GetLastName() { return lastName; }
    public String GetRegion() { return region; }
    /*You can increase get method to connect your variables.*/
}

 */*Above class like .net mvc model classes.*/*

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace YourProjectName
    {
    public partial class Form 
    {
        private List<Employee> employees{ get; set; }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtTitleBox.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

        public List<Employee> LoadCombobox()
        {
                List<Employee> employees= new List<Employee>(); 
                var employeeList = correlation.ComputeCorrelation();
                var bSource = new BindingSource();
                bSource.DataSource = employeeList;
                employees.Add(bSource.DataSource);
                return employees;
        }

        private void LoadYourCombobox_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          employees= LoadCombobox();
          foreach (Employee employee in employees)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(employees.GetFirstName());
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

***When the user selects the item u can use below code block:***

```
Employees employee = employees.Where(f => f.GetFirstName().Equals(comboBox1.SelectedValue)).FistOrDefault();

if (employee!= null)
{
    //do work
}
```

***or u can use below code block:***

```
if you want the firstName: comboBox1.SelectedValue

if you want the index: comboBox1.SelectedIndex
```

*I hope the codes help you.*

Comment: Confusing post.  Why would the Employee class require an IList parameter in the constructor?  Why does the "form" inherit from the Employee class?  Why would you only put the first names of employees in the combo list, and not the entire employee object?

Comment: I put only firstName because he wanted to drop with firstname. LoadCombobox() method is  a bit complicated you're right. I will try to edit.